# How to send messages from MySQL to a Java web app,when data is inserted or updated?

Tags: java, mysql, jsf-2

I'm making a MySQL database for a Java-based web application. I need to send messages from  MySQL to the Java webapp when data is inserted or updated. How might I approach this?

Comment: Get a descent book/tutorial on MySQL **and** JSF in the first place. What you want to do is basically to set up some property during database access calls that would be later displayed in your view.

Comment: Like @skuntsel says, if you don't have a background in either of those technologies, you need to learn them separately. Only then will any answer provided here make sense. Per [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), this not a good fit for the Q&A format here. Voting to close.